# HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL with have doPost method in Servlet

Tags: java, http, post, servlets

This is my problem...
This file I have in my project: login.html and UserLoginServlet

This is login.html:

```
<form action="/gitowcy/login" method="post" class="main-form needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12 col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="login">Login</label>
                <input type="text" name="login" id="login" class="form-control" required>
                <div class="invalid-tooltip">Niepoprawny lub pusty login!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12 col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Hasło</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" required>
                <div class="invalid-tooltip">Niepoprawne lub puste hasło!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Zaloguj</button>
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/gitowcy/login")
public class UserLoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

@EJB
UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    resp.setContentType("text/html");

    String login = req.getParameter("login");
    String password = req.getParameter("login");
    PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();

    if (login == null | login.isEmpty() | password == null | password.isEmpty()) {
        writer.write("ERROR");
        return;
    } else {
        if (userRepository.validateUser(login, password)) {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/gitowcy/logged");
            dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
        } else {
            writer.println("USER DONT EXIST!");
        }
    }

    writer.close();
}
```

}

I have 1 user in my db called admin/pass. I write this data in form and click to Login. The program moved me to link http://localhost:8080/gitowcy/login and always print message: "HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL"...

I don't have any idea how can I solve this problem...
Pls help me...

Comment: The URL specified on the `action` attribute of the `<form>` HTML tag should point to the end-point you specified in the servlet `/gitowcy/login`

Also, in the servlet, you are mapping both username and password to the same variable name `login`.

Comment: Can you add the line of login.html, where <form> starts?

Comment: Ops my bad in mapping.

Comment: Start form: <form action="/gitowcy/login" method="post" class="main-form needs-validation" novalidate>

Comment: And what's your web.xml?

Comment: I didnt change it

Comment: Unless you run your web application in the ROOT context, you have to add `${request.contextPath}` to the form URL, i.e. `<form action="${request.contextPath}/gitowcy/login" method="post" class="main-form needs-validation" novalidate>`.

Comment: Maybe I can add file jboss-web.xml with code: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee/jboss-web_10_0.xsd" version="10.0">
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>?

Comment: If you run it on JBoss it can help, but using `${request.contextPath}` is the correct way.